# Proving all Solutions of a Polynomial Cannot all be Real

Tags: calculus

If, a, b, c, d and e are all real numbers how could I prove that the 5 solutions of the equation:
$$f(x) = x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e == 0$$
cannot all be real valued if:
$$2a^2 < 5b$$

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the factorization of polynomials into linear factors using their roots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are 5 zeros, then the first derivative has 4 zeros, the second has 3 zeros, and the third has 2 zeros, all counted with multiplicity. The condition on $a$ and $b$ is exactly the condition that the third derivative has *no* real zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm just a little confused still regarding how $2a^2 < 5b$ fits in with the third derivative of $f(x)$. Is it simply the fact that because $a^2$ is less than $b$ that there can't be any real zeros?

Comment: @NateyG, compute the discriminant of the third derivative.

Comment: Ah, I see. Got it now. Thanks.